# Reference to find dielectric constants and dielectric relaxation time

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reference-request

I am working on a Master degree and need to know the following data :

- The static (low frequency) dielectric constant of isopropanol at 25 °C
- The Optical (high frequency) dielectric constant of isopropanol at 25 °C
- Dielectric relaxation time (τ) of isopropanol at 25 °C

Could someone please provide me with these values and a reference or link to a book contains these data?